# Create a new column in pandas taking into account a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column from a condition, the idea is that if the first column has the value of 0 take column two, and if not leave the first column.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'Buyer': ['Carl', 'Carl', 'Carl'],
'Quantity': [18, 0, 5],
'Hoja':[2,4,8],
'Salida':[0,0,0]})

def remean_points(row):
    if df1.Quantity==0:
        row.Salida = Quantity
    else:
        df1.Salida= row.Hoja
    return row

df1.apply(remean_points, axis='columns')
```

However I find the following error, and I do not know how to solve it, I appreciate your help.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-7c3222c7a9a8> in <module>
      6     return row
      7 
----> 8 df1.apply(remean_points, axis='columns')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6876             kwds=kwds,
   6877         )
-> 6878         return op.get_result()
   6879 
   6880     def applymap(self, func) -> "DataFrame":

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
    184             return self.apply_raw()
    185 
--> 186         return self.apply_standard()
    187 
    188     def apply_empty_result(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    294             try:
    295                 result = libreduction.compute_reduction(
--> 296                     values, self.f, axis=self.axis, dummy=dummy, labels=labels
    297                 )
    298             except ValueError as err:

pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction.compute_reduction()

pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction.Reducer.get_result()

<ipython-input-20-7c3222c7a9a8> in remean_points(row)
      1 def remean_points(row):
----> 2     if df1.Quantity==0:
      3         row.Salida = Quantity
      4     else:
      5         df1.Salida= row.Hoja

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1477     def __nonzero__(self):
   1478         raise ValueError(
-> 1479             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1480             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1481         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is complaining that the truth value of a Series is ambiguous, this means that you have a Series object full of booleans and the if doesn't know what to do with it. It expects a single boolean.

This is happening because of this line `if df1.Quantity==0:`, you are asking every value of the column if it is equal zero and that's why you have a boolean Series. My guess is that you are trying to check only the value `Quantity` for that specific row received by the function, so you should change df1 for row.

---

If I understood your objective correctly, this is the function and function call you want:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'Buyer': ['Carl', 'Carl', 'Carl'],
'Quantity': [18, 0, 5],
'Hoja':[2,4,8],
'Salida':[0,0,0]})

def remean_points(row):
    if row.Quantity==0:
        return row.Quantity
    else:
        return row.Hoja


df1["Salida"] = df1.apply(remean_points, axis ="columns")
```

PS: If you indeed desire to use df1 that way I would advise you to also pass it as a parameter for your function to avoid nasty side effects later on